# Positioning divs based on array elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to make a project where an array is created with a set number of elements ranging from 1 to any number. A div is then created for each element, where the distance from right is determined by (some number * array[div number]) + "px". Something like this:

```
<div id = "demo"></div>

var d = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var array = [1,2,3];
//insert some code I don't know here
d.style.right: (array[1] * 20) + "px"
```

Here is where I get stuck because I am very much a beginner and I don't know how to make a new div for each array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
var demoElement = document.getElementById("demo");
var array = [1,2,3];

array.forEach((x, i)=> {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerText = array[i] + ' element';
    el.style.paddingLeft = (array[i] * 50) + 'px';
    demoElement.appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<div id="demo">Demo Element</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work perfectly. I changed the code slightly so that all the divs would be on the same line, but other than that, it's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Iterating over an array**

If your array is of fixed length, you can fetch each element of the array using array[x]. However it is better to use a for-loop to fetch each item.

```
for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs 3, 5, 7
}
```

More on this topic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

**Creating elements**

In order to create HTML element from within Javascript, you can make use of the `Document.createElement()` method. You would need to write something like

```
let element = document.createElement("div");
```

You can read more on this topic and see a few examples on the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you asked for.

```js
var array = [1,2,3];
array.map((elem,i) => {
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += `<div class="generatedDiv" id="${elem}">${elem}</div>`
})
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.generatedDiv{
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is what you want to achieve:

```js
const d = document.getElementById("demo");
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

arr.forEach(e => {
  const child = document.createElement("div");
  child.className = "demo__children";
  child.textContent = "child" + e;
  child.style.left = e * 20 + "px"
  d.appendChild(child);    
});
```

```css
.demo__children {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id = "demo"></div>
```